# in which folder put image for setting to background of layout android

Tags: android

i am putting the image in three of the drawable,drawable-hdpi and drawable-ldpi for supporting all type of screen but when i see the output of background image in 240*320 screen resolution the background image is not as clear as origional so my question is where to, means in which folder i put the background image for supporting it all type of screen size and density, maens then my image should not distorted or bluer...

i am using the background image of size:320*480

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put different same image in drawable-hdpi,mdpi and ldpi.Depending on the density of devices they will take the images from the corresponding folder.

With different devices you should have same image but with different size and density.for You can search in internet the specifications of devices.If density is less than 160 then put image in ldpi,if 160 then use mdpi and if 240 or above use hdpi.Also change the size of image to the screen size of corresponding device.Hope it will help.

Comment: what  background image size we should have to use for 240*320 resolution screen?so that avoid obscuring of image?

Comment: actually i have 320*480 size of image and put in all the 3 folder but in small screen it is  not too clear as in samsung galaxy s2 when i test in galaxy fit

Comment: thats the question i was asking ...what should be  size of image to the screen size of corresponding device?

Comment: If you are using the image to cover whole screen then size of image is same as screen size else according to your need.Got it now?

Answer (score 2):

make one folder name

```
drawable-nodpi
```

put your image in that and use it and dont keep that image in other folders.

the image will not be scaled or stretched.

**Anoher Way**

*the best way is to make 3 different size images and put int drawable-ldpi(240X320),drawable-mdpi(320X480),drawable-hdpi(480X800) folder with the same name.*

TO LEARN MORE PLEASE VISIT THIS LINK.
[Supporting Multiple SCreens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)